# Is this off-topic question really off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Dig, if you will, the picture...  Here we have a question posted on SO:

[how to remove the batch file you just used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860052/how-to-remove-the-batch-file-you-just-used)

This was closed as "Off-Topic".  But, it's really not much different than every regex question ever asked, and I think it's something that another user may ask in the future.  In short, I think this question will get googled again, and I'm wondering why it's considered off-topic.  If it is, in fact, off-topic I may need to adjust my future handling of such questions, so if anyone could enlighten me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't it belong more to SuperUser? I mean, it should have been migrated.

Comment: No, it's on-topic on SO, but it is a duplicate of the question in the comments.

Comment: Just because others have the same question doesn't make it on-topic. And it was probably closed because you can look that up in a gazllion documents.

Comment: re: SuperUser; so why does SO have [tag:batch-file] and [tag:command-prompt] tags if those questions should be asked on SU?  I'm not trying to be a jerk, I'm just trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: Now I'm going to have "When Doves Cry" going through my head all day.

Comment: It's still better than anything by Pitbull.  ;o)

Comment: You can't put a Pitbull song in my head because I don't know any. ;p

Answer (score 6):

As the close reason says:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**

Let's take a look at this question:

> How do I remove a batch file I just used with a batch code line? Like
>   a code that does this:
>
> `remove thisbat.bat`

Here's my thoughts:

- It doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved
- The OP hasn't shown any research efforts -- sharing your research **always** helps
- There's no explanation of the problem. The question is a bit vague and it is difficult to answer the question accurately in its current form (in this case, the [OP just got lucky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860198/1438393))

Some useful links:

- [How to ask a good question? -- Stack Overflow Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
- [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by Jon Skeet

Comment: Yup. You got it.

Comment: Fair enough, except for the last point which is obviously false because it was answered.  But look at every regex question and you'll see the same.  I still think it's a valid question and one that will get hits in the future.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I would probably have worded that last point, "is difficult to answer accurately", but, yeah.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I agree with you on the "cannot be answered point" but it's a huge mistake to think that a question that could get views is automatically a valid question.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: I just argued with someone some time ago that because "you were able to guess the correct answer" doesn't make the question more valid or good.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Thanks, that's what I actually wanted to say. Updated :P

Comment: Technically, the OP did post the expected results.  And you could argue that his "remove thisbat.bat" was his attempted solution.